# Alert on FTP file server upload

Tags: java, .net

How to scan network directories / or a FTP server and alert me via email each day saying what new files have been upload to the server?

I have about 20+ directories at work with images that get updated by external parties, but rarely get told that they put the files there. Would make things easier if I had an alert along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

In dotNet you can use the FileSystemWatcher class to get notified when new files arrive or when files change: [FileSystemWatcher on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a quick and easy solution you can use the freeware [FTP Guard](http://www.ftpguard.com/index.html) which provides exactly the functionality you describe.

Just schedule it to run e.g. every morning and you will have the information you need.